# Significant terms aggregation over a list field against itself

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

I have documents of the following format:

```
{ "my_field": ["foo", "bar", "baz"] }
{ "my_field": ["foo", "baz"] }
{ "my_field": ["foo", "bar"] }
```

I would like to find out which `my_field` term pairs occur most commonly together. I have tried using `significant_terms` aggregation like:

```
{
    "aggs": {
        "fields": {
            "terms": {"field": "my_field"},
            "aggs": {
                "significant_pairs_with": {
                    "significant_terms": {"field": "my_field"}
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This works perfectly apart from the very top result in each aggregation is the duplicate of the parent result, e.g. `"foo"` always appears with `"foo"`. Is there a way to filter these out? Or do I need a different aggregation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could filter them out using a scripted scoring heuristic.  Something like:

```
{
    "aggs": {
        "fields": {
            "terms": {"field": "my_field"},
            "aggs": {
                "significant_pairs_with": {
                    "significant_terms": {
                        "field": "my_field",
                        "script_heuristic": {
                            "script": {
                                "lang": "painless",
                                "source": """
                                if (params._subset_freq == params._subset_size) { 
                                    0 
                                } else { 
                                    1 
                                }"""
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }                   
}
```

However, if you care about the relative ordering of results then that heuristic is too simple.  It filters out the terms you don't want, but it's a flat score for everything else.  You could use something like [the example from the Elasticsearch documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-significantterms-aggregation.html#_scripted), modified here to with casts to `double` for better results:

```
else {
    (double)params._subset_freq / (double)(params._superset_freq - params._subset_freq + 1)
}
```

I think theoretically you could use the four provided params to reimplement most of [the built-in heuristics](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/tree/master/server/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/search/aggregations/bucket/significant/heuristics).  For most of them you'll want to start with [the NXYSignificanceHeuristic base class](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/master/server/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/search/aggregations/bucket/significant/heuristics/NXYSignificanceHeuristic.java), which defines the computeNxys() method.

[JLH](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/master/server/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/search/aggregations/bucket/significant/heuristics/JLHScore.java) is one of the simplest to re-implement.  [This Search Nuggets post](http://blog.comperiosearch.com/blog/2015/06/10/how-elasticsearch-calculates-significant-terms/) explains it in more detail.  It's pretty heinous to write in the painless scripting language, but I think this is a decent first approximation:

```
"source": """
    if (params._subset_freq == params._subset_size 
    || params._superset_size == 0 
    || ((double)params._superset_freq / (double)params._superset_size) == 0) {
        0
    } else {
        (((double)params._subset_freq / (double)params._subset_size) - ((double)params._superset_freq / (double)params._superset_size)) 
        * ((double)(params._subset_freq / (double)params._subset_size) / ((double)params._superset_freq / (double)params._superset_size))
    }
"""
```

Comment: Nice references!